# Run PHP from the command line

Tags: command-line, php, environment-variables, xampp, php-cli

I have installed [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) v1.8.3 for my PHP development. I am new to Ubuntu, so I don't know how to set environment variable for PHP which is located at `/opt/lampp/bin/php`.

I can run PHP scripts from `localhost` just fine, but I wanted to run them from the command line as well.

I want to set this variable for every user, since I am the only one who uses this system.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Environment variables are set in `/etc/environment`. You will find the `$PATH` variable in this file. This variable stores the path to binaries in various locations.

To add `/opt/lampp/bin` to the location searched for binary files, just append this path preceded by a `:` to the path variable.

For example, if the `$PATH` variable was:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

add `/opt/lampp/bin` to the end of it, so that it becomes:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/lampp/bin
```

After doing this, do a `source /etc/environment`.

Comment: @sud_the_devil: Just edited my answer.

Comment: I opened the file by issuing **sudo subl /opt/lampp/bin/php** and then appended the location as you asked me to do . Here's the link to the opened file. 
[PATH](http://i.imgur.com/bywNrYr.png)


Do I need to restart my system after that??

Comment: No, you don't need to restart your system. Can you paste the output of `echo $PATH` after you have added the path and done a `source /etc/environment` and `ls  /opt/lampp/bin/php`?

Comment: This is the output of **echo $PATH**:
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

And this is the output of **ls /opt/lampp/bin/php**:
/opt/lampp/bin/php

Comment: @sud_the_devil you are required to edit the environment file and not the php executable. Your command should be `sudo subl /etc/environment`

Comment: @sud_the_devil Add only `/opt/lampp/bin`, not `/opt/lampp/bin/php` which is the executable file.

Comment: @ Srihari @RaduRădeanu Thank you guys, my bad ... It works now

Comment: @Jobin : I have added your response as the answer .

Answer (score 28):

To open an interactive php shell, just type in a terminal:

```
php -a
```

As for opening a file, just:

```
php filename.php
```

Comment: The OP problem is: *I don't know how to set environment variable for php which is located at /opt/lampp/bin/php .*

Comment: @darent Thanks. This was the first search result I got from Google and `php -a` was exactly what I looked for.

Answer (score 13):

As an alternative to `/opt/lampp/bin/php`, to run a php script from the command line, you just need to install [php5-cli](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/php5-cli):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

And run your script with:

```
php myscript.php
```

---

editor's note: depending on your version, you may need to install `php7.0-cli` etc instead

Comment: `php5-cli` is in a different package.

Comment: @Wutaz On what planet? ([hint](http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2011/09/execute-php-5-script-command-line-ubuntu-linux/))

Comment: Doesn't work. Instead of execution a script it just prints file content like `cat` does

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
php /var/www/html/yourProjctFolder/yourFile.php
```

This will call your php file and output if you have written echo or print statement

Comment: No, wrong.It just prints file content like `cat` does. No execution

Comment: @Green It seems that you don't have proper set up of php on your system.

Comment: It seems that you have to type `-f` between `php` and filename to make it work => `php -f file.php`