# Can you acess MySQL via the command line through XAMPP

Tags: command-line, mysql, xampp

A few months ago, I installed XAMPP on a Linux computer I've been using. I've been using it for a project, and it works perfectly, but I don't seem to be able to access mysql from the command line, even though I can accsess my databases perfectly fine from phpMyAdmin. I've tried using the `mysql` phrase, along with the `mysql -u root -p` phrase, but neither yield anything, as I only get the following error:
Command 'mysql' not found, but can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0     # version 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3, or
sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.3  # version 1:10.3.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
```

I was under the impression that, by installing XAMPP for Linux, it would come with mysql. I know you can access the prompt using `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p`, but I keep thinking there must be an easier way to access it. Is this not the case, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: XAMPP uses MariaDB now. See [XAMPP - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)

Comment: You just need to add the location to your `PATH` - see this related answer [Run PHP from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/a/447257/178692)